# How to create a completed instance of org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Tags: java, spring

How to create a dummy instance of `org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture`?

It should represents a completed task with a given result.

Comment: It could help you https://www.javatips.net/api/org.springframework.util.concurrent.listenablefuture and https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.util.concurrent.SuccessCallback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `String result`, you can use following:

```
    String result = "result";
    ListenableFuture<String> future = new AsyncResult<>(result);
    String dummy = future.get();
```

However, if you need, any `object` can be wrapped in `AsyncResult`.